Missing reference, "ChecksumAttribute" not found
I have a missing reference problem ("Eco.UmlCodeAttributes.ChecksumAttribute") in a new project, using today's versions of the MDriven Designer and MDriven Framework.
I can't find anything with this name ("ChecksumAttribute") on disk so it's probably part of some assembly.
How can I fix this error?
Using VS2022 v17.10.4, Win 10.

// RIL
There's Always a Solution
-- me

Install the latest version of these two packages from Nuget package manager in visual studio,
EcoCore and EcoSqlServer, by MDriven AB. Rebuild your project.
